# goback instruction without a button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

just a quick question guys, how can I simulate a tap on the back button in a navigation controller in Objective C without using a button ? Do you happen to know what the instruction is ?

Help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```